# Given $v_1(t) = 1 + t, v_2(t) = t + 2t^2$ and $v_3(t) = 1 - t^2$, check that the set {$v_1(t), v_2(t), v_3(t)$} is a basis of the vector space ...

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Given $v_1(t) = 1 + t, v_2(t) = t + 2t^2$ and $v_3(t) = 1 - t^2$, check that the
> set {$v_1(t), v_2(t), v_3(t)$} is a basis of the vector space $\mathbb R_2[x]$ of real polynomials of degree less than or equal to two and with real coefficients.

My attempt

$\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 + \gamma v_3 = 0 = \alpha (1,1,0)+ \beta (0,1,2) + \gamma (1, 0, -1) = 0$

$\alpha + \gamma = 0$

$\alpha + \beta = 0$

$2 \beta - \gamma = 0$

$\alpha = 0, \beta = 0, \gamma = 0$

So it is linear independent.

Now I need to check if $v_1,v_2,v_3$ generates all $R_2[x] $

$ax^0 + bx^1 + cx^2 = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 + \gamma v_3 = $

$\alpha + \gamma = a$

$\alpha + \beta = b$

$2 \beta - \gamma = c$

is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Now you should solve for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ in terms of $a,b,c$. Anyway, if you know that $\Bbb R_2[x]$ is a vector space whose dimension is 3, then any three linearly independent elements of it form a basis. This means that you don't need to check that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ form a generating set.

Comment: You have not completed the proof. You need to give the values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ independently in terms of $a, b, c$.

Comment: One could compute the determinant of the matrix where the entries in the $i$-th column are the coefficients of $v_i(t)$. This is nonzero if and only if the $v_i$ form a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @whoisit told you, you have not completed the proof.
You need to solve $\begin{cases} \alpha+\gamma=\color{Red} a \\ \alpha+\beta=\color{Red} b\\ 2\beta-\gamma=\color{Red} c\end{cases}$ for any vector $x\mapsto {\color{Red} a}\times1+{\color{Red} b}x+{\color{Red} c}x^2$. You will find $\begin{cases} \alpha=-{\color{Red} a}+2{\color{Red} b}-\color{Red} c \\ \beta={\color{Red} a}-{\color{Red} b}+\color{Red} c\\ \gamma={\color{Red} c}-2{\color{Red} b}+2\color{Red} a\end{cases}$.

For example, with $v:x\mapsto {\color{Red} 7}\times1{\color{Red} {-3}}x+{\color{Red} 4}x^2, v=-17v_1+14v_2+24v_3$.